How to Adjust Wave Height in a CSS Liquid Animation Without a Static Line Appearing?
I'm working on a fuel tank animation with a wave effect using in Angular. The wave effect is created using a ::before pseudo-element on a .liquid div. The animation looks great, but there is an issue: when I adjust the wave height or position, a static line appears at the top of the wave, creating an unnatural effect.


.tank-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.tank {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); /* Decreased opacity for more realistic glass */
    box-shadow: 
        0px 8px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), /* Deeper outer shadow for depth */
        inset 0 0 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); /* Softer inner light reflection */
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px); /* Slightly stronger glass blurring effect */
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15); /* More subtle glass border */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.liquid {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%; /* Fuel level */
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(249, 212, 35, 0.9), rgba(194, 78, 0, 0.95)); /* Richer color for diesel effect */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.liquid::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px; /* Adjust to create wave effect near the top */
    left: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); /* Increased opacity for more definition */
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.7; /* Adjusted for more prominence */
    animation: wave 6s infinite linear;
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes wave {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateX(-25%); /* Move partially to the left */
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-50%); /* Move fully to the left */
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateX(-25%); /* Move partially back to the right */
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0); /* Return to the starting position */
    }
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); /* Light glassy sheen on top */
    border-radius: 20px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px); /* More pronounced glass distortion */
    pointer-events: none;
}

.tank::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); /* Increased opacity for more reflection */
    box-shadow: 
        inset 1px 1px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), /* Increased shadow for depth */
        2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* Deeper outer shadow */
}

.tank::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
<div class="tank-container">
  <div class="tank">
      <div class="liquid" [style.height]="liquidHeight"></div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>




can you share screenshot of what is wrong when the height is set? its unclear

In CSS liquid animations, adjusting the wave height without causing a visible static line requires fine-tuning both the animation parameters and wave properties. The appearance of a static line usually happens if the wave reaches or goes below the container boundaries, revealing a background line where it loops. Here’s how you can adjust the wave height smoothly:

Use transform: translateY for Wave Height Adjustment
Adjusting the wave's translateY property in CSS lets you control how high or low the wave appears within the container without affecting its looping animation. Here’s an example setup:



.wave-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px; /* Adjust height based on your layout */
  width: 100%;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200%; /* Extend width for smooth looping */
  height: 100%;
  background: url('wave.svg') repeat-x; /* Use an SVG or gradient for the wave effect */
  background-size: cover;
  animation: waveAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  transform: translateY(10px); /* Adjust Y position for wave height */
}

@keyframes waveAnimation {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(10px); /* Adjust starting Y position */
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(10px); /* Move wave across the container smoothly */
  }
}




Have you tried the code? If you are giving a runnable snippet, please make it runnable, ie with the related HTML. Don't just dump AI generated answers here please.
